# SuperLU - Distributed Sparse Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix

I was trying to create a sparse distributed Matrix with SUPERLU, but I'm getting some troubles:

basing on SuperLU documentation, I'm using following function,

```
void dCreate_CompRowLoc_Matrix_dist(SuperMatrix *A, int m, int n,
int nnz_loc, int m_loc, int fst_row,
double *nzval, int *colind, int *rowptr,
Stype_t stype, Dtype_t dtype, Mtype_t mtype);
```

but it seems that, whatever I pass to, segmentation fault happens.

I've tried passing a very simple 2x2 matrix with 2 nonzeros only, running with 1 process (that means something like)

```
m = 2; 
n = 2;
nnz_loc = 2; 
m_loc = 2; 
fst_row = 0;
nzval[0] = 1.0; 
nzval[1] = 2.0;
colind[0] = 0; 
colind[1] = 1;
rowptr[0] = 0; 
rowptr[1] = 1; 
rowptr[2] = 2;
...SLU_NC, SLU_D, SLU_GE
```

and I continue having a segmentation fault error

I assume I'm not fully understanding the function usage, 
can anyone help me on this (or, if more information are needed, please let me know)

many thanks
Simone

---

Update/1
just as further information, I've noticed that Row Local matrices are correctly created (with correct position for each element/row) but they seems not to be "collapsed" into a global Supermatrix A-

Comment: See [this page](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/superlu_code_html/supermatrix_8h_source.html) for the NCformat... for one thing, you don't have enough `colptr`s (`colptr[]` has `ncol+1` entries).